# Wide table in scrollable div squishing cells

Tags: jquery, html-table, width, cell

I have a table with an arbitrary amount of columns and rows and the **<td>** tags have a height and width.  My issue is when I put it in a **<div>** with **overflow:scroll** and a width less than the width of the table, the table cells get squished, even though I have a specified width on them.

I've done a bunch of testing and it appears if I specify the width of the table, it looks fine.  There's got to be a CSS way of doing it without specifying the table width.

This is the gist of my code and css along with a JSFiddle demo (the number of columns doesn't matter, so long as it's greater than the width of the div

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="Colors">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><td>
            <td><td>
            <td><td>
            <td><td>
            <td><td>
            <td><td>
            <td><td>
            <td><td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table.Colors td {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    font-size:.8em;
    line-height:25px;
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow:scroll;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nightcatbooks/L7gwwyL4/

Comment: Sorry about that.  Link had been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a `min-width` for the cells so that they don't get squished:

```
table.Colors td {
    width:25px;
    min-width:25px;
```

Might not work on older browsers (IE7? not tested)

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pxth1hph/

Comment: Thank you!  I knew I was missing something uber simple. :)